# The least possible value for $x^2-2xy+2y^2-6y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x,y$ are real numbers .How to find the least possible value for $x^2-2xy+2y^2-6y$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** continue so that it stays true:
$$x^2-2xy+2y^2-6y=(x-y)^2+(y-3)^2-\dots$$

Comment: It isn't always that such questions reduce to a sum of squares plus a constant - but it is always useful to see if there are squares involved in some minimisation problem, because squares of real numbers are non-negative.

Comment: what should i do after finding that "constant "?

Comment: Notice where the bottom is of a square, e.g. graph $y=x^2$, and that should give you a good hint of where to find the bottom.

Comment: Use that $h^2\ge 0$ for all real $h$. Thus a minimum of such is when $h=0$.

Comment: We will get a minimum for $y=3$ and $x=y$. And the minimum will be $-9$.

Answer (score 3):

This method works for differentiable functions of one or more real variables:

1. Check whether the function has a minimum. In this case it does,
   but if instead of $-2xy$ you have $-3xy$, the formula doesn't have a minimum.

   (someone improve this answer by telling how to do this please)
2. Find the derivates:

   - $\cfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} = 2 x - 2 y$
   - $\cfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y} = -6 - 2 x + 4 y$
3. Set the derivatives equal to zero and solve the system of equations:

   - $2x - 2y = 0 \quad\implies\quad x = y$
   - $-6 - 2 x + 4 y = 0 \quad\implies\quad -6 + 2x = 0 \quad\implies\quad x = 3$

   In this case only one solution is found, but in the general case there could
   be more solutions, even infinitely many. The solutions are called critical points.
4. For all solutions found, check which one yields the smallest number.
   Since we have only one solution, this step can be skipped.

So the minimum of $x^2 -2xy+2y^2-6y$ is $-9$ at $x = 3, y=3$.